# How to scan QR codes with a Nintendo 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

Okay, I really think I'm slightly insane. I looked for guides like this one, but I just can't find that on my 2DS camera software.

As I can't find such a guide for the Nintendo 2DS, I think that it uses the same software as the 3DS.

This is what guides tell me to look for in the camera software:

[image]

But I just don't have this button visible. This is how my camera app looks in the bottom screen:

[image]

That parrot gives me some basic help for the camera, but there seem to be no magic to morph him into a QR code button. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top picture is from the camera app built in to the main menu (accessed by pressing `L` + `R` at the home screen).

Your photo, however, is from the app "Nintendo 3DS Camera", which offers some more advanced photography options, but apparently not the ability to scan QR codes.

Comment: Rofl, that's just right. Thought it would be the same software. I got the exactly picture as in the guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've figured it out already but, Don't go to the Camera App just hold down L + R and the camera that you're looking for will pop up, I was having this problem too.