# How do i scan QR codes on my 3ds?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I saw pictures with a little icon on the bottom left of the camera thing, but i just don't have that. it's just blank.

[image]

The one annotated in red doesn't exist for me. How do I get it?

Comment: Should we assume you've done system software updates?

Comment: I don't think the 3DS system software supports QR codes, but other software might. The Mii Maker, for instance, can read QR codes. Is that what you're trying to do, scan QR codes of Miis to import into the Mii Maker?

Comment: @Nolonar The 3ds camera CAN read QR codes. (I have a 3ds myself. By pressing the L+R buttons at the same time, you can activate the simple/fast camera. This had that QR code button.)

Answer (score 2):

This feature was added system software version 3.0.0-5. If you want to use that feature you must use that version or higher. [[1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152330/73060)]

Only the mini version of the camera app - acessed by pressing L or R on the home menu - has the QR code feature.

(sources: me, 3dbrew, [Dustin Martin's Arqade Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/152330/73060))

Comment: Do you have any sources or information you can use to back this up?

Comment: Will this do? http://i.imgur.com/qp98zt6.png